# PyInstaller Output Executable Error - Windows cannot access the specified the specified device, path

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I wrote a Python script to collect data from a certain website by using Selenium, the script works perfectly, and when compiling it with PyInstaller (Windows 11) it still works well on my system, nevertheless, when trying to launch the executable on some other PC with the same OS I get the message "Windows cannot access the specified the specified device, path...", I've already tried to compile it as a single file but I get the same result.
[image: Error Message]

This is what the **_internal** folder looks like, the python312.dll file is there.
[image: This is the output folder created by PiInstaller]